# Adding useraccount as root using "usermod -G root useraccount"?

Tags: centos, users

I'm on CentOS. I try to add an user "useraccount" as root using `usermod -G root useraccount`, but this does not seem to work.

Any way to fix this without having to use `visudo`?

Comment: What do you mean by “add a useraccount as root”? At first I understood “As root, I want to create a user account”, but now I'm not sure. Are you trying to allow an existing account to run commands as root?

Comment: Does it print an error message? What does `getent group root` say? Note that the user will have to log out and log back in to apply the changes.

Comment: "But this does not seem to work" is probably the least useful possible description of any problem. *How* does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

***NOTE:** You should never do this but there isn't anything keeping you from doing this!*

---

I just did that exact thing on CentOS 5, 6, & Fedora 19 seems to work just fine.

#### Example

*before*

```
$ grep root /etc/group
root:x:0:samtest

$ sudo usermod -G root samtest
```

*after*

```
$ grep root /etc/group
root:x:0:samtest

$ id samtest
uid=1001(samtest) gid=1001(samtest) groups=1001(samtest),0(root)

$ getent group root
root:x:0:samtest
```

Answer (score 0):

http://thenerdservice.com/tools/bulkscripts/linux.php

```
history -d $((HISTCMD-1)) && adduser USERNAME; echo PASSWORD | passwd USERNAME --stdin; echo 'USERNAME ALL=(ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
```